# Unable to set underline location using the VGA Underline Location Register

Tags: assembly, x86, dosbox, real-mode, vga

I am writing a terminal driver for custom Operating System. I want to the terminal to understand common vt-100 escape sequences that control the cursor location, shape, colors etc. So while implementing the 'underline/underscore' feature, I want to write to the Underline Location Register [VGA/SVGA Video Programming - CRT Controller Registers](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/12au-cs140/pintos/specs/freevga/vga/crtcreg.htm#14), but it is not working. No underline is showing up (actually I do not know where to look). Below is the code and a screenshot of the DOS box.

```
  ; Read the Underline Location Register
  mov dx, 0x3D4
  mov al, 0x14
  out dx, al      ; 0x14 is the index of the Underline Location Register

  mov dx, 0x3D5
  in al, dx

  ; I want an underscore at 6th scan line, so I and 0b00101 with the value I got before
  and ax, 0xE5        ; 0b1110 0101
  push ax
    ; I write back the value to Underline regiser
    mov dx, 0x3D4
    mov al, 0x14
    out dx, al
  pop ax

  mov dx, 0x3D5
  out dx, al
```

However no outline is appearing. I am writing some text (second hex value) after I have set the Underline Register, but no underline.
[image]

Comment: You may wish to read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA-compatible_text_mode#Underline

Comment: DOSBox isn't the greatest environment to testing an operating system under as it often doesn't bother to implement things if no game actually uses them.

Comment: @RossRidge I have also run the same on a Computer hardware as well.

Answer (score 1):

To get underline to work properly; you'll need to:

- set the underline register
- reprogram the pallet so that "foreground attribute = 1" is the only color you want underlined text to be
- realize that "100% VGA compatible BIOS interface" does not mean "100% VGA compatible at the hardware level"
- realize that "100% VGA compatible at the hardware level" is limited to extremely rare ISA video cards from IBM that were released in 1986 and obsolete in 1987 (and everything that actually exists now ranges from "0% hardware compatible" to "99% hardware compatible", where "0% hardware compatible" is becoming the most likely possibility due to everything switching to UEFI).
- realize that if you want something that works properly you have to use a graphics video mode, where you can support things that are necessary for VT-100 (underline, bold, "double height" and "132 column mode") in addition to things that were optional for VT100 (e.g. the graphics processor), plus things that VT-100 couldn't do (e.g. support more character sets than just "UK" and "USA ASCII", have a mouse cursor, ...).